# Magento 2.2(checkout page): Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: magento2.2, json

I have read other posts here in this forum but I am having a hard time finding the solution to my problem.

On the checkout page, the shipping method does not show and is only loading forever. (we are using the normal checkout page, not the one step checkout)

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>           at JSON.parse ()
>           at Object.process (error-processor.js:28)
>           at Object. (customer-address.js:61)
>           at fire (jquery.js:3232)
>           at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.js:3362)
>           at done (jquery.js:9842)
>           at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery.js:10311)